# Failed annotation in AppEngine connected Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have created an App Engine connected Android project using Eclipse 4.3 (also tried older version) and all the latest plugins (AppEngine 1.8.5).

When i run my AppEngine project, and open the `http://localhost:8888/`, the page displays correctly and starts searching the datastore for registered devices. Then i get the below warning in my console. It seems to be something wrong with some of my classes not being annotated i think, and i have searched high and low for how to fix it. Can onyone help me?

```
        okt 06, 2013 11:51:49 AM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
        WARNING: Class com.test.MessageEndpoint was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
        okt 06, 2013 11:51:49 AM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
        WARNING: Class com.test.EMF was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
        okt 06, 2013 11:51:49 AM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
        WARNING: Class com.test.DeviceInfoEndpoint was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
```

[image: Screenshot of libs:]

Answer (score 2):

In your persistence.xml file add the entity classes, like this :

```
<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>com.watch.project.a</class>
        <class>com.watch.project.b</class>
        <class>com.watch.project.c</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>  //important
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true" />
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

I hope this fixes your problem ! worked for me :)